# Connecting two files or classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have two pages(each having a class) that that needs to be connected, page1(file1.py) and page2(file2.py).

I want to open page2 with a button that will be on page1. As mentioned the codes for each page are in separate files, file1 and file2. 
I used import file2 but as soon as I run the program it opens and runs file2.py which I dont want. I want to open page2 via button when the user needs to open it.

Any suggestions???

Regards

Khisrow

Comment: You should have posted an example of your code.

Comment: There are countless ways to implement "pages" in tkinter. Without knowing how you're doing it, we can only guess. Please provide a  [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Just put the second page inside a `class`, `import` that inside a `function` and call that. Then give the `function` as the `command` to a `Button`.

Like this:

Module_one:

```
import tkinter as tk


def test_func():
    import Module_two
    Module_two.TestClass()


root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: test_func())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Module_two:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        import tkinter as tk
        root = tk.Toplevel()
        lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Test Label")
        lbl.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It almost works but when it calls the page2, it just displays the adages of  page2 without the buttons that should be on the page2.

Comment: @user3064089 Can you explain your problem a little bit more? because I don't think there should be any problem with this. Or you can put your code in your question via an edit, So I will fix any issue in that. :)